# File system error when writing

Tags: file-system, lineageos

I recently encountered a problem using Threema on LineageOS 15.1: I noticed that whenever I want to download a picture posted by someone else in a conversation, I get the message "Could not download message". A logcat reveals, that an excepction is thrown when opening the file:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ch.threema.app/files/data.blob/017c31a18e3325c75d3564fd3565b144
```

I used adb shell (as root) to create an empty file:

```
# whoami
root
# echo "" > /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ch.threema.app/files/data.blob/017c31a18e3325c75d3564fd3565b144
sh: can't create /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ch.threema.app/files/data.blob/017c31a18e3325c75d3564fd3565b144: Invalid argument
```

So the same error occurs in the shell, even if I am logged in as root.
Apparently, once the file is created, it can't be written to:

```
# echo "asd" > 017c31a18e3325c75d3564fd3565b    
# echo "asd" > 017c31a18e3325c75d3564fd3565b
sh: can't create 017c31a18e3325c75d3564fd3565b: Invalid argument
```

The permissions of newly created files are set to

```
-rw-rw---- 1 u0_a71 sdcard_rw 4 2018-12-31 13:45 017c31a18e3325c75d3564fd3565b
```

Any ideas what is causing this? Is this a misconfiguration / permission issue? Or is this a problem with the file system (I used both f2fs and fat32)?

Comment: Can you use `strace`? Do you have SELinux enforcing?

Comment: strace yields `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/ch.threema.app/files/data.blob/017c31a18e3325c75d3564fd3565b144", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC|O_LARGEFILE, 0666) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
`

Comment: As to SEAndrodi: `getenforce` => `Permissive`

Comment: dmesg tells me: `WARNING: at ../../../../../../kernel/samsung/kminilte/fs/sdcardfs/inode.c:743 sdcardfs_setattr_wrn+0x48/0x60()`, `sdcardfs does not support setattr. User setattr2.`

Comment: That's the thing. Problem is with emulated filesystem. You can try direct path `/data/media/0/Android/data/ch.threema.app/files/data.blob/` (`ext4` or `f2fs` whatever) and it should work. Also try with short filename. Need to check `sdcardfs` source to see why it can't handle this filename.